# How to remove listview item when the condition is false?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a follow system on flutter.What i want to do is,when the condition is shown false,i want to give a function that does not show  `posts[index]` item . How can i do it?

```
PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
          return FutureBuilder<User>(
              future: callUser(posts[index].author),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData ? (posts[index].isfollowed(snapshot.data.id, user) == true ? Scaffold(...) : //RemoveIndexCondition)  :  
Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.pink,valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pinkAccent)));
              });
        },
        itemCount: posts.length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to read your code - most IDEs or editors like VS Code will automatically format it to make it read able :)

Here is a version of your code which is nicely formatted. Also I moved the Scaffold moved outside the PageView, as it seemed better. Now what is your requirement?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('PageView Test'),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FutureBuilder<User>(
              future: callUser(posts[index].author),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? (posts[index].isfollowed(snapshot.data.id, user) == true
                        ? Center(child: Text("Followed"))
                        : Center(child: Text("Not Followed")))
                    : Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                            valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                Colors.pinkAccent)));
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: posts.length),
    );
  }
```

In order to only show pages for followed posts you can filter the posts list before constructing the PageView:

```
  Future<List<Post>> followedPosts(List<Post> posts, User user) async {
    var followed = <Post>[];
    for (var post in posts) {
      var postUser = await callUser(post.author);
      if (post.isfollowed(postUser.id, user)) {
        followed.add(post);
      }
    }
    ;
    return followed;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('PageView Test'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
        future: followedPosts(posts, user),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Center(child: Text("Followed"));
                  },
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                      valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                          Colors.pinkAccent)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.What i want now is that when the 
(posts[index].isfollowed(snapshot.data.id, user) == false

it just skips the item and does not show it at all. It does not even give the text "not followed".

Comment: So you do not want a Page for posts that are not followed? Obviously you could filter your posts list before invoking the PageView with the filtered list.

Comment: Exactly.
But how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use your code as it is, and add `Container()` after the `:`.

```
yourConditionisTrue ? Scaffold(...) : Container();
```

Comment: I used that,but it gives a blank view instead of showing the widget that meets the condition.I want to modify it as it only shows the widget that meets condition.

Comment: Can you write the condition that you want to check, and the item you want to display in a clear code format please?